# Certificate errors when using a custom domain for an AWS websocket API Gateway (using CloudFormation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, aws-api-gateway, amazon-certificate-manager

I've been having some trouble setting up my a custom domain for my websocket API Gateway in AWS. I keep getting certificate errors. I have a certificate setup already, and some cloud formation scripts. That look right. Everything deploys correctly, but I keep getting this error about certificates.

```
$ wscat -c ws.example.com
error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ws.example.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I checked the certificate it's returning, and the serial number does not match the certificate I've created in ACM.

Here's my CloudFormation script:

```yaml
  WebsocketApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-ips-ws-api
      ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
      RouteSelectionExpression: $request.body.action
      ApiKeySelectionExpression: $request.header.x-api-key

  WebsocketStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties: 
      ApiId: !Ref WebsocketApi
      Description: Websocket Api Stage
      StageName: base
      AutoDeploy: true

  WebsocketDomainName:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref WebsocketDomain
      DomainNameConfigurations:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref WebsocketCertificateArn
          SecurityPolicy: TLS_1_2
          EndpointType: REGIONAL

  WebsocketDomainMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref WebsocketApi
      ApiMappingKey: base
      DomainName: !Ref WebsocketDomainName
      Stage: !Ref WebsocketStage

  WebsocketDnsRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      Name: !Ref WebsocketDomain
      Type: CNAME
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt WebsocketDomainName.RegionalDomainName
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt WebsocketDomainName.RegionalHostedZoneId
```

Let me know if there's I'm missing some infromation.

Any help would be appreciated, been wracking my brain over this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the protocal when using wscat ? You should use it like :

```
wscat -c wss://socketserve.example.com
```